# Terminate EC2 instance from the EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance which is launched on a schedule, once a week. The problem is that I have no way of terminating it.

Basically when the EC2 instance is launched, it runs its initial setup (the User-Data) and then I need it to terminate.

Is there any command that I can add to the end of my User-Data for my EC2 instance that can be used terminate itself?

Comment: `shutdown -h now` if you set the instance's `InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior` to `terminate`.

Comment: See: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally when shutting down the OS of an EC2 instance the instance will enter a "stopped" state instead of a "terminated" state. You can change this behavior by setting `InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior` to `terminate`. This will cause your instance to terminate instead of stop when the OS halts.

You can then use `shutdown -h now` to terminate the instance. This has the benefit of not needing to give the instance access to terminate ec2 via the AWS API.

Comment: This looks like what I need. Ill try this out. Thanks!